# Objective C - Group elements from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Well, I am going to give a try explaining what I want to realize.

I have the JSON scheme like:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "title": "Title #1",
      "date": "1446930000"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title #2",
      "date": "1437782400"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title #3",
      "date": "1437912000"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title #4",
      "date": "1446930000"
    },
    {
      "title": "Title #5",
      "date": "1437912000"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have to group the elements by time (for example, by day). Already tried to index the **objects[]** array, making 'dates' array (**dates[]**) then index the array again, index the **dates[]** and check if objects ***array[i]*** = **dates[q]**. But this method is really poor made and has no sense when there are lots of objects.

How else can I group them?

Comment: You need to provide a better description of what you want to end up with.

Comment: @zaph Glorfindel already gave the solution to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [mutable dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:objects.count];
for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
    if (dictionary[object[@"date"]]) {
        // the date was already found
        [(NSMutableArray *)dictionary[object[@"date"]] addObject:object[@"title"]];
    } else {
        // the date was not found
        dictionary[object[@"date"]] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:object[@"title"]];
    }
}
```

A dictionary uses a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) to make sure the lookups are quick - much quicker than looping over all keys.